# Is there an alternative to CSS?

Tags: css

Is there a style sheet formatting language alternative to CSS?  Or is CSS the current single language for doing Style Sheet formatting type things?

I looked at the write up of CSS on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) and a few other comments about CSS and became discouraged about the lack of full support for CSS in the different Layout engines, so I am just curious if there is an alternative or I must learn to also use CSS filters.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: CSS if fine*, it's IE which is broken. (* CWG excepted)

Comment: If only there were an alternative...I shudder to think of the amount of human effort that has been wasted trying to do things in CSS which should be simple but aren't...

Comment: the funny thing is that you have to type style="text/css" in style related tags... :)

Comment: there are css frameworks: bem, oocss, mvcss, less, smacss, stylus

Comment: Check out Rolfs answer below. CSS is made by and for programmers. We need something made by and for graphical designers. I've used CSS as a programmer for around 8 years now, and I think it's ridiculous to work with complex systems of graphical design by _coding_ low-level rules like we do. There must be a better way.

Comment: It's not even for programmers, either.  In programming, you have an order of execution laid out from top to bottom in your document.  In CSS you don't even have that.  You have a bunch of properties blindly being accessed from and applied to an entirely different document, a complex, static web of string that you can't start analyzing until you find the front end.  You can't tell where some effects even come from because things are blindly cascaded throughout the document.

Comment: CSS is *declarative* because the web is fluid (is the user on a giant monitor, a laptop, a smartphone, or a screenreader?), so graphic designers can't use the techniques they're used to in, say, Photoshop, where the canvas size is under their control.  Likewise, because different user agents render differently, you have to say "Here's what I want" rather than "here's how to do it," like a computer programmer would.

That's not to say CSS couldn't use a lot of improvement and become easier to use; just that it needs to be different in nature from what both designers and coders are used to.

Comment: 14 years later CSS has gotten _a lot_ better

Answer (score 69, accepted):

CSS is the only real option.

Browser support for CSS should not be a major concern (in most cases) once you learn the ins & outs of CSS. The key to understand about CSS is that its purpose is to define the style of an HTML document and it should be separate from the content.

You'll need practice in learning how to make things degrade gracefully in browsers that don't support features. The basic idea here is that you should make the lowest common denominator (Internet Explorer usually) work "good enough" that it doesn't take away from the user experience, and provide the niceties for users with better browsers. Also, **don't** develop for Internet Explorer first. Leave it until last, then fix its bugs. Doing things the other way around (IE first) is much harder.

You also have the option of using JavaScript to set styles, but that is not recommended because you should avoid applying styles within JavaScript since JavaScript is meant for logic, not styles.

There are 3 (depending how you look at it) components to a web page:

- **HTML** - for content
- **CSS** - for styling your content
- **JavaScript** - for applying additional or dynamic logic to your content

Comment: The key line in there is the second sentence: "Browser support for CSS should not be a major concern (in most cases) once you learn the ins & outs of CSS." People who complain the most about CSS being broken know it the least.

Comment: +1: ...for an excellent answer. The suggestion to code to standards first and _then_ patch the bugs in IE's cruddy rendering engine is definitely the way to do it.

Comment: When you know CSS well, IE7 actually behaves quite well.

@Rob: hear, hear +1.

Comment: making an application with css is a real torture for an app developer. however except Cappuccino.org, there has been very few attempts to solve this very obvious problem. there are rumors that xcode will be producing html5 soon, if that happens, it will put an end to this chaos, not because xcode is the best, it will guide others to implement SDK's for the web, and browsers will come with UI components (they will still use css & html to display it but who cares, we won't see/use/know/learn them)

Comment: @Devrim Those types of tools already exist, and have for a number of years. The problem is that they don't have any intuitive understanding of your site design. They make insufficient choices and hard-to-maintain code. Hand-written CSS is here to stay.

Comment: @Dan if you call it 'a site' you are right, if you call it 'an app' you are not - as i think my applications on my desktop have every understanding about my needs. Similar approach needs to be adopted by browsers. I am talking about making a photoshop/games/powerpoint/eclipse on the browser. Suggesting html and css for apps simply is not plausible along with thinking browser apps won't evolve to that point or desktop apps are different than web apps. They will merge at one point and it's coming closer.

Comment: @RobAllen I say the same thing about Malbolge, my favorite programming language.  People who think it is impossible just don't know it well enough to realize how great it is.

Comment: "Doing things the other way around (IE first) is much harder."
It's called progressive enhancement... and everybody should use it.

Answer (score 89):

You guys are all trying to answer the question from a programmer's perspective. I think the original poster was looking for an alternative which is more graphic-friendly - one that would offer a different concept.

Even if CSS3 gets adopted cross browser, I believe that the CSS way of laying out stuff (inline box, floats, margins, etc) is awful. I am a programmer, but my father is a graphic designer, and I am pretty sure that the layout software they were using 20 years was in some aspects easier and more advanced than CSS.

Comment: Excactly! CSS and and the cognitive workflow of graphical layout is not on the same abstraction level.

Comment: IMHO , this answer is so under-rated , even in 2015.

Comment: **"my father a publisher and graphic designer, and I have bathed in graphic design since my smallest age, and I dare to say that the publishing software they used 20 years ago was more advanced and user-friendly than HTML/CSS nowadays."**

... The difference is that your father wasn't designing for different screen sizes, screen readers, different browser versions (with differing capabilities), etc.  Designing for print is much, much simpler than designing for screen display, and hence CSS is more complex than languages designed to lay out print media.

Comment: I recommended Postscript as a language and PDF as a delivery vehicle. I was beaten up and voted down in a viscous manner. The droids on SO don't like opinions.

Comment: @J Taylor,  Lose it will ya. Design using any medium isn't easy. It's a skill, art and science just as much as writing CSS and HTML is. Please respect the arts. 

Postscript was designed to handle different sizes of media and it has been around for decades. The whole point of HTML and CSS is to get the web browser to render something that Postscript does by default.

HTML and CSS are awful!

Comment: @J.Taylor well well. But how comes CSS cannot answer simple questions like "select the last row of items of a set of flex items?" "select the parent of element with class `.my-class`?" css has come a long way. But let's face it it didn't grow so well. It is not really well done.

Comment: CSS suffers from side effects to many rules, and also basically it is nothing but global variables, with complex inheritance rules. This is everything that is supposed to be wrong in programming - but somehow it is OK because "CSS is not a programming language" - never mind that it now gets media queries and variables.

Comment: A decade later, with grid and Flexbox and the like, it’s a lot better.

Answer (score 42):

**Yes** there is, it's called **[LESS](http://lesscss.org/)** and it really adresses most CSS's code readability problems.

You can both compile it on the server or on-the-fly client-side with **[less.js](http://fadeyev.net/2010/06/19/lessjs-will-obsolete-css/)**.

For production, I recommend setting up a build script that compiles it (in [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) this is piece of cake with [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and [grunt-contrib-less](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-less)).

---

**Edit:** There are also other options worth mentioning, even if I'm using and recommending LESS.

[**SASS**](http://sass-lang.com/): Ruby folks love this one. It is not a super-set of CSS like LESS, but instead uses its own syntax. To cope up for this, they developed SCSS, which *is* a CSS super-set and is similar to LESS.

[**Stylus**](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/): like LESS, it is coded in javascript, but this is commonly used from Node.js. I can't vouch for it, since I didn't try it out yet, but it is very mature so if it has a feature you want, definitely go for it.

[**Turbine**](http://turbinecss.github.io/): This one was coded in PHP. Not much traction.

[**Switch CSS**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/switchcss/): Maybe Python hackers will want to look into this. Even less traction.

If you're feeling even more alternative, there's also [CSS Cacheer](http://shauninman.com/archive/2008/05/30/check_out_css_cacheer), [CSScaffold](https://github.com/caiomorcego/csscaffold), [DtCSS](https://code.google.com/p/dtcss/), [CSSPP](https://github.com/jeremyboles/csspp) and even [something](http://pornel.net/css) by [porneL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27009/pornel).

---

Other stuff you might want to check out:

[**Compass**](http://compass-style.org/): A full-on CSS authoring framework for the Ruby guys.

[**WinLESS**](http://winless.org/): A drag&drop LESS compiler for Windows, it's super cool and you really should check it out.

[**LESS Elements**](http://lesselements.com/), [**Preboot**](http://markdotto.com/bootstrap/), [**LESSHat**](http://lesshat.com/) and [**even.less**](https://github.com/bisrael/even.less): Libraries of mixins and constants for LESS.

[**Bootstrap**](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/): A framework developed by Twitter. Also related: [**HTML5 Boilerplate**](http://html5boilerplate.com/).

[**Normalize.css**](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/): an alternative to [**CSS resets**](http://www.cssreset.com/). There are many resets, however, as the developer of one, I have to say: most are crap. If you're not going to make your own, then just use this one.

---

**Update**: [Since 1.4](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#140-beta-1--2), LESS has `@extend` too. Be sure to use 1.4+ if possible! This completes the reasons to choose LESS over SASS I think.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't seem to be an alternative to the *model* itself.

Comment: @naxa and why would you want that? The model is great (stylesheets), the implementation is terrible (CSS). These tools tackle just the implementation, which is why they're so popular.

Comment: Because competition aids progress. What do you mean by "stylesheets"? I associate it with cascading and distinct file/section from text. But there is more, the box model, using labels and containers merged into the text (with html). Is there implementation [in]dependency? - eg. can stylesheets applied to anything but html/xml? (What if you wrote a stylesheet and want to apply it not to to a not-gt/lt-based text or to a binary format? Were you to reuse any stylesheet implementation or out there on your own in the wild?)

Comment: @naxa what I meant was, the concept of having style separated from content is a great model, which is what I call "stylesheets". And by implementation I meant the CSS syntax, but I agree that having LESS instead of CSS is just like using CoffeeScript instead of Javascript. And well, there are binary markup formats, so I don't see why you couldn't have binary stylesheets, but if you think about it they probably wouldn't be found by that name, because stylesheets solve a human problem (writing styles for many documents), not a machine problem (or we'd be still using `<FONT>` tags).

Comment: I downvoted because these are preprocessors, not alternatives. They lay on top of CSS and output CSS at the end. So it's just one abstraction level higher - but not an alternative.

Comment: @Sumit Thanks for providing rationale for a downvote. Still, I believe the question can be interpreted by many people looking for it as "is there an alternative to *having to write CSS*?" (In the same sense as jQuery being an alternative to the DOM API, for example - not technically true but true for the guy writing code).

Comment: No CSS processor addresses CSS readabilty problems. It is really up to the coder. They also are not alternatives, but simply extenders or modifiers to CSS.  A real alternative to CSS is Postscript, but Adobe got a bit greedy and shortsighted.  They could have owned the web!  Before you say PS is difficult, when was the last time you saw PS code?  Never?  My point exactly, but it is ubiquitous and all the hardwork is done behind the scenes by orogrammers, leaving designers free to design.

Comment: @ATL_DEV So you would rather have a world where "view source" returns a garbled mess of glorified draw calls? I don't like CSS very much, but I can easily understand how it works, how I can monkey-patch a website with poor design (with an user style), and it just isn't as bad as postscript would be, plus WYSIWYG is only ever good in theory. Also nothing is stopping you from "coding" your website as PDF files you type into MS Word. You can have your idea in action right now and see how that looks like.

Comment: You're looking at it from the failed open source philosophy.  The rest of the world just wants to create, print, search and publish content without being programmers. HTML and CSS are too complex for the masses to use effectively. Ironically, it has only enabled online corporations to lock and control content by providing easy-to-use facilities that hide its ugliness.

Comment: @ATL_DEV Oh come on, "the masses" aren't web developers. They can barely figure out how to use social networks, let alone set up their own server. And even if they somehow managed to do that, Microsoft Word + save to HTML is probably enough. You're not gonna get stacy and chad to figure out Postscript either, it will just be Microsoft Word + save to postscript. As much as I'd like CSS and HTML to make more sense, the better alternatives would probably look like many of the languages that target them (e.g., LESS/Sass/Stylus and Slim/Pug/HAML). You can try these right now.

Answer (score 20):

Yes.

As everyone else said, CSS is your only real option, but **there is another language for  "style sheet formatting type things"** on the web, called eXtensible Stylesheet Language (XSL), particularly the subset of the spec that became known as [XSL-FO (formatting objects)](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/06/21/deviant/index.html).

At one point, depending on who you asked, it was intended to [compete or collaborate with CSS](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/06/21/deviant/index.html).

Comment: The W3C has a good summary of the relationship between XSL and CSS: http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS-vs-XSL

Answer (score 13):

Grid stylesheets (GSS) : [GSS](http://gss.github.io/)

way better

Comment: SIte no longer exists.

Answer (score 8):

Wide-spread CSS does not get full support in all browsers...how should an (unknown) alternative reach this goal?

Comment: By having a layout model that is predictable, intuitive, and fixes problems in new versions instead of leaving in the mistakes.

Answer (score 7):

Well, CSS 2.1 is pretty well supported by nearly every browser. (except IE6)
It's easy to write gracefully-degraded CSS once you know the safe subset. (So that even unsupporting browsers won't totally mess the page up)

See http://www.quirksmode.org for CSS browser compatibility hints.

Comment: +1 for quirksmode - every user starting with CSS needs to know about that. I'd add that IE7 is pretty bad with CSS2 too, and unfortunately most of the web (and almost all corporate networks) are IEs 6 and 7 only, so you have to be careful with CSS2.

Answer (score 6):

> became discouraged about the lack of full support for CSS in the different Layout engines

I think jQuery has some ways to make css more compatible across-browsers, i.e. if you specify some attributes using jQuery then it will try to make sure to use a work-around for browsers that don't support certain features.

There's also a project called [CleverCSS](http://sandbox.pocoo.org/clevercss/), you might want to check it out. It's not an alternative to it though, just a slightly different way to define it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is dead.. :-(

Answer (score 5):

An alternative  a long time ago JavaScript Style Sheets (JSSS) was a stylesheet language technology proposed by Netscape , if anyone interested i'll drop you some links
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Style_Sheets

here is the proposal  http://www.w3.org/Submission/1996/1/WD-jsss-960822
i think this was a good  idea but sadly css won, but maybe some parts got integrated with javascript??

Also maybe instead of using css you could use svg for some text effects look at the examples

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh410107.aspx

and some animations

http://svg-wow.org/text-effects/text-effects.xhtml

some buttons effects https://www.svgopen.org/2008/papers/86-Achieving_3D_Effects_with_SVG/

here is a cooleer example for styling text you should look at this http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/scalable-vector-graphics-text/

Answer (score 4):

There is no alternative to CSS right now and this is a Good Thing. The browser vendors, W3C, WHATWG etc have a hard enough time agreeing on a single spec as it is, can you imagine what would happen if there was more than one spec?

Anyway I found that once you learn CSS, you gain knowledge of what particular things break what and either learn to work with it or avoid it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "There is no alternative to CSS right now and this is a Good Thing.",i beg to differ.

Comment: It's a Good Thing within the narrow specification of Good that Darko outlined.

Answer (score 4):

> I looked at the write up of CSS on
>   Wikipedia
>   (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)
>   and a few other comments about CSS and
>   became discouraged about the lack of
>   full support for CSS in the different
>   Layout engines, so I am just curious
>   if there is an alternative or I must
>   learn to also use CSS filters.

CSS is *the* standard. There is no alternative.

All browsers support the basic CSS features. Each new version of each of the (four?) main browser lines comes with increased support for the standard, but websites that use these features will be broken to any users in an earlier version. There are two answers to this:

1. "Graceful degredation" (or its twin, "Progressive enhancement" - google it), in which the page takes advantage of advanced features if they're available, while still continuing to work if they're not.
2. Who are your audience? If you're lucky enough to know that 99.8% of visitors to your website will be using at least IE7, then you don't need to worry about the CSS features that are broken in IE6. This will depend on your own business though, so check the facts first.

The worst thing you can do is code to the quirks of a single specific browser, because that leads to a page that's broken not only on other browsers, but even on later versions of the same browser.

Answer (score 4):

[Elm-ui](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mdgriffith/elm-ui/latest/) is a package for [Elm](https://elm-lang.org/), which is a functional language compiling to HTML/JS/CSS.

It completely rethinks the way we think about layout & style, and I think such a project is long overdue.

The author, Matthew Griffith, talks about Elm-ui [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ie-gqwSHQr0).

Answer (score 3):

The only alternative is the deprecated formatting support that HTML itself has, like the `<font>` tag.  But you don't want to do that.  8-)

Comment: If you use <font> you might also experience mildly intense hatred from other web developers like me :p (At least if they have to read/fix your code...)

Answer (score 3):

Nope, CSS is the way to go now. There's nothing wrong with the format itself (I personally quite like it actually), but rather only the browser support for it - especially regarding IE. Once we have all major browsers supporting [CSS3](http://www.css3.info/), things should be fine - though I'm not too optimistic over when that will happen.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the format itself?  To cite Jeff Atwood : "In short, CSS violates the living crap out of the DRY principle. You are constantly and unavoidably repeating yourself.   (
    Lack of variables so we have to repeat colors all over the place.
    Lack of nesting so we have to repeat huge blocks of CSS all over the place. )   That's my experience too, you can become good at it, but it has nothing to do with its merit as language

Answer (score 2):

No (mostly)

If you want to create layouts that work in the maximum number of client machines then you'll have to learn CSS.

If you can limit your users to IE8, Chrome, Safari and Firefox then you can probably get away with CSS2, otherwise you're going to have to learn all the differences with CSS1, along with the myriad broken things - especially in IE5 and 6.

HTML 3.2 includes some formatting tags (such as `<font>` or `<center>`) but you can't do much with them.

*Why only mostly?* - If you can assume that users have either Flash or Silverlight and build web applications for them. Then your layout will be perfect, but it'll need a client side plugin (which not everyone has) in order to work. I'd only go down that route if you need really rich client UI.

Comment: Actually, you can do quite a lot with HTML 3.2 formatting tags and table-based layout. For example, this is my old website (about 10 years old): http://www.itek.at/alt/ganzneu-eng.html

Comment: you actual site is done with layout table too. you loose *accessibility, *ability for maintaining , *a lot of those 30% internet-users with handycaps, *machine-based interpretation (like google) *...

Comment: Nothing you can do with 3.2 is acceptable in modern development on bandwidth, accessibility or maintenance grounds. There's just no purpose to downscaling if you aren't required to.

Comment: @ammoQ - yeah you can, but it takes a while and is a mare to change. Scroll back to the early 00s and site design was about slicing up a big image and putting the resulting jigsaw into a table. I did plenty of it and it's not that good compared to the modern stuff. You can do a site that way, but it will look like it was last updated in 2002.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the current state of CSS support is pretty horrible.

I think the best approach is to write CSS according to [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/) and then add fixes for all the bits where the various browsers don't properly comply. It's often worth avoiding some bits of CSS if you though (z-levels for example have really mixed levels of support in a lot of browsers).

Answer (score 1):

Zoli is right. "xslt is an alternative"

XSLT turns XML into a rendered web page, just like CSS turns HTML into a rendered web page. 
Just note that you can't mix XSLT with HTML or CSS with XML.

I've used both CSS + XSLT to create rendered web pages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ! [sass](http://sass-lang.com/) may be an option

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't have more upvotes, given its popularity with the Ruby on Rails crowd.

Comment: Please share more details. Is there any browser out there which is able to work with sass directly?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Postscript is the most likely alternative to CSS. The problem is that it requires Acrobat to view it on the desktop or on the web. It is far superior to CSS and maintains design intent and scales across all devices, including printers, plotters, phones, tablets and just about anything with a Postscript interpreter.

Postscript has a ZERO learning curve, unless you're implementing it for a particular device. It is programmed by millions of programmers, graphic artists, artists, professional printer and even the lowest skilled home computer user. All you need to do is select print or save from any application's menu.It does support linking and field inputs.  Is it searchable?  It is and PS-based documents frequently appear in Google's search pages.

Although, it can be viewed from a web browser in the form of a PDF, it isn't a native browser language like HTML and CSS.  Why isn't it, if it is so easy and powerful? When the web was starting out, Adobe was too shortsighted and greedy open up the language. They wanted to sell licenses to their PS engines and their content creation products. To Adobe, giving away a PS browser was like giving away the Goose and the golden eggs.

Answer (score -6):

xslt is an alternative

It is more powerful than css.

It is more difficult to learn and to use it.

Comment: how is XSLT an alternative to CSS? They do completely different things.

Comment: I think they may meen XSL-FO, which is fine but AFAIK dosn't work in a browser.

Comment: No, I do not mean XSL-FO, just XSLT.
In XSLT you can express transformations, therefore with XSLT you can express any kind of formatting that can be expressed with HTML. OK, that is less then what CSS can do, but I have not said, that XSLT is a perfect alternative.

XSLT stuff is also in a separate file, like CSS, and from HTML one can refer to the XSLT file. Because of these 2 properties, one can do formatting for his/her HTML-based document without much redundancy. 

XSLT works in Firefox, IE, I have not tested others.

Comment: No, Zoli. You can not do formatting with XSLT. You can interfere with the original code, transform it, add to id, remove from it etc.. but you cannot style it ...