# CSS Gradient Constants

Tags: html, css

I often visit [this](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) website, to create a nice gradient for my html elements.

Example of CSS that is created:

```
myElement {
    background: rgb(30,87,153); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(41,137,216,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(32,124,202,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Now when I have multiple different gradients on my elements you can imagine that the CSS file gets quite messy.

Is there a way that I can define these gradients as constants or some other way to create a simple tidy solution?

So all I would have to do was something like this

```
myElement {
    background:GRADIENT_BLUE_GREEN;
}
```

Thanks! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not yet, without a CSS pre-processor. Though [CSS variables *are* coming](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/), with the usual W3.org caveats of "sometime, one day. Eventually..."

Comment: You can try it with PHP

Comment: Imo you can drop most of those properties though. `background: linear-gradient(red, green)` works in most modern browsers now. Edit: You could also use SASS @mixins or the awesome autoprefixer (https://css-tricks.com/autoprefixer/)

Comment: you could use something like prefix-free.js which will allow you to declare the w3c version and should prefix this correctly.

Comment: @Professor.CSS could you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: @jammycoder: This is what I would do (i.e. take the w3c declaration from colorzilla and then add this to the head section): http://jsfiddle.net/zq7cqufp/

Comment: Most of those prefixes (e.g., -ms-) never existed and you don't really need the rest. Check [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) for browser compatibility and which prefixes you need to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with pure CSS, but fortunately you can use `a-built-on CSS` softwares like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and many other [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925653/is-there-an-alternative-to-css)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it easy on yourself with `CSS Preprocessors` but the actual file size is not going to change.

Answer (score 0):

Like stated in other answers, declaring variables is not possible with pure css.

you can however, work around that and still achieve the desired tidy result using pure css - by using css animations.

you can define a static animation that will run once very fast and keep the last frame, and use the animation name as a variable for your elements for a tidy css:

```css
.myElement {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  animation: GRADIENT_BLUE_GREEN 1ms 1 forwards;
}



/* you can define those in a separate file and link it where needed */

@-webkit-keyframes GRADIENT_BLUE_GREEN {
  to {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(32, 124, 202, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1)));
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes GRADIENT_BLUE_GREEN {
  to {
    background: -moz-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(32, 124, 202, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1)));
  }
}
/* define more keyframes per browser as needed */
```

```html
<div class="myElement"></div>
```